# Scraping: Only first images are scraped, rest is filled with placeholder. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, screen-scraping, puppeteer

I am scraping a job site using JavaScript with a the headless browser Puppeteer.

I am grabbing the first 6 company logo items from a job site successfully. However, after these first 6 logos, it will suddenly stop printing out the real logos (hence, providing me the `src` URLs), but instead inputs a placeholder image.

What could be the reason for this?

Just FYI, I am grabbing the images like this:

```
const image = card.querySelector('div.job-element__logo img').src
```

Comment: They are probably lazy loaded with javascript. Do they have any attributes for the real source?

Comment: Occasionally devs will load in placeholder images so there isn't a content jump or a noticeable change on the page as the actual desired images load in. Try looking at the data on the element by logging `.dataset` - it's possible the actual `src` will be listed in that object.

Comment: Its this site I am trying to get the company logos from: https://www.stepstone.de/5/ergebnisliste.html?stf=freeText&ns=1&qs=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22358898%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22Software+Engineer%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22jd%22%7D%5D&companyID=0&cityID=0&sourceOfTheSearchField=homepagemex%3Ageneral&searchOrigin=Homepage_top-search&ke=Software+Engineer&ws=hamburg&ra=30

Comment: Seems like it has to do with the lazy load. I don't see another source dataset.

Comment: There is a `data-src` attribute on the ones with placeholder images

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean. How can I grab this, since its not a class attribute? Like this? [data-utag-click-data]?

Comment: `dataset.src` should get you the src.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The images are being lazy loaded.**

The correct [`src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/src) of the images that have not been loaded yet are stored in a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) called `data-src`. You can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) in conjunction with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to filter and scrape all of the correct image [`src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/src) values:

```
const images = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.job-element__logo img'), e => e.dataset.src ? `https://www.stepstone.de${e.dataset.src}` : e.src);
});
```

If you would like to scrape the position, company, description, and image for each job, you can use the following solution:

```
const jobs = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.job-element'), card => {
    const position = card.querySelector('.job-element__body__title').textContent.trim();
    const company = card.querySelector('.job-element__body__company').textContent.trim();
    const description = card.querySelector('.job-element__body__details').textContent.trim();
    const image_element = card.querySelector('.job-element__logo img');
    const image = image_element.dataset.src ? `https://www.stepstone.de${image_element.dataset.src}` : image_element.src;

    return {
      position,
      company,
      description,
      image,
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Only thing left is that it provides me with all the logos as an array within each of my array items (jobs).

Comment: `const position = await page.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.job-element')).map(card => {
      const position = card.querySelector('.job-element__body__title').innerText
      const company = card.querySelector('.job-element__body__company')
        .innerText`

Comment: `const description = card.querySelector('.job-element__body__details')
        .innerText
      const image = Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll('.job-element__logo img'),
        card =>
          card.dataset.src
            ? 'https://www.stepstone.de' + card.dataset.src
            : card.src
      )    })`

Comment: @MarkusMühlerdt I have updated my answer to include a solution for gathering the position, company, description, and image for each job.

Comment: It works! This is awesome - thank you very much, Grant!